# Rails where from(string) greater or equal to today

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, string, datetime, where-clause

I have a request table with column `from:string`

I would like to get `Request.where("from >= ?", Date.today)` but from is string. Is there a way to get all request where from greater or equal to today without changing the column string to datetime?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You can create an index with the appropriate transformation, then query the index, or handle your coercion on every query.

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert the string to a date in SQL.

`Request.where("DATE(from) >= ?", Date.today)`

I do think it is way better to change the column type though when possible. Storing a date as a string is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the `from` column string is formatted in the usual string-date format (e.g. "2017-01-15") then just convert Date.today to string.  The string ordering will automatically be equivalent to date ordering.

```
Request.where("from >= ?", Date.today.to_s)
```